# Install tensorflow GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

i'm trying install tensorflow gpu on win10.
my steps:

1. install Python 3.5.2
2. install Nvidia CUDA(v9)+cudnn
3. copy cudnn files on prog.files directory NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit
4. install tensorflow gpu (pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu)

   C:\Python>python
       Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
       Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

   > > > import tensorflow as tf
   > > >           Traceback (most recent call last):
   > > >             File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
   > > >               return importlib.import_module(mname)
   > > >             File "C:\Python\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
   > > >               return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
   > > >             File "", line 986, in _gcd_import
   > > >             File "", line 969, in _find_and_load
   > > >             File "", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   > > >             File "", line 666, in _load_unlocked
   > > >             File "", line 577, in module_from_spec
   > > >             File "", line 906, in create_module
   > > >             File "", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
   > > >           ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.

   ```
   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
       return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
     File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
   ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
       from tensorflow.python import *
     File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
       raise ImportError(msg)
   ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
       return importlib.import_module(mname)
     File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
   ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.

   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
       return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
     File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
   ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


   Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

   See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

   for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
   above this error message when asking for help.
   ```

If I install tensorflow without GPU- all OK.

Comment: Do you have a supported GPU, like an nVidia one with CUDA cores?

Comment: ye. nVidia GTX 690(2 GPU)

Answer (score 2):

It is really important to follow the [TensorFlow install instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows#requirements_to_run_tensorflow_with_gpu_support), thereby choosing the correct versions:

> - **CUDA® Toolkit 8.0**. For details, see NVIDIA's documentation Ensure that you append the relevant Cuda pathnames to the %PATH% environment variable as described in the NVIDIA documentation.
> - The NVIDIA drivers associated with CUDA Toolkit 8.0.
> - **cuDNN v6 or v6.1**. For details, see NVIDIA's documentation. Note that cuDNN is typically installed in a different location from the other CUDA DLLs. Ensure that you add the directory where you installed the cuDNN DLL to your %PATH% environment variable.
> - GPU card with CUDA Compute Capability 3.0 or higher. See NVIDIA documentation for a list of supported GPU cards.

Currently, the newest version for the CUDA Toolkit is 9.0, but for Tensorflow you need version 8, which is available on the [CUDA toolkit archive](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive):
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-80-ga2-download-archive

And for the cuDNN (Deep Neural Network libraries), you need to select **cuDNN v6**, and not the newest version v7: https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download

Finally, be sure to put the Windows `%PATH%` variable to the CUDA bin directory (where the dll libraries are).

Then, you can install tensorflow:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

If it does not work yet, you might want to restart first.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i resolved it,
If you are using pip or pip3 you have less chance succeeding in first time.

- Uninstall Python,CUDA, CuNN, Tensorflow-gpu (if you already installed)
- Install ANACONDA or MINICONDA
- Open ANACONDA prompt and run following command:

  conda create --name tf_gpu tensorflow-gpu
- This will create an environment tf_gpu whcih will install all compatible versions of Python, CUDA, CuNN and Tensorflow
- once all the packages installed open the ANACONDA prompt and type the following command

  conda activate tf_gpu
- This will change the conda '(base)' to '(tf_gpu)' environment
- Then type python as usual to activate the python prompt
- If you want to deactivate the 'tf_gpu' environment

  conda deactivate

Answer (score 0):

Currently, these versions are supported.  Do not try to install more recent versions.

Visual Studio 2015. 
CUDA 9.0. 
cuDNN 7.0 (make sure to copy the dlls to the right directory). 
Python 3.5.

Then you can install tf

Answer (score 0):

I have tried so many blogs myself. I always got one or the other errors.
However, the following worked perfectly for me.

```
conda create --name tf_gpu tensorflow-gpu
```

You simply need to have Nvidia drivers installed on your system. You don't need to install CUDA and CudNN, and worry about the version compatibility.

This command will install the CUDA and CudNN alongwith the compatible version of Tensorflow for you.

Comment: Side remark: as of now tensorflow-gpu 2.3 for Windows on Anaconda is faulty. A workaround can be found [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/12194#issuecomment-751700156).

Answer (score 0):

Finally this documentation worked for me: [Anaconda | TensorFlow](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/)

The document is self-explanatory. If you already have an environment, just run:

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu
```

Important notes:

- GPU TensorFlow uses CUDA.
- On Windows and Linux only CUDA 10.0 is supported for the TensorFlow 2.0 release. Previous versions of TensorFlow support other version of CUDA.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have referred to many blogs and StackOverflow answers, but none of them worked for me. However, I have at last found a procedure that worked perfectly fine for me. So, I have an NVIDIA GTX 1650 GPU, and below are the steps that I followed to get GPU enabled TensorFlow up and running:

**1)** Install the NVIDIA Drivers (Studio Driver) and restart your PC.

**2)** Download the visual studio 2019 Community version (In it, install all the c++, python/AI/DL dependencies).

**3)** Install Cuda 10.1 (update 2,released in august,2019).

**4)** Install CuDNN 7.6.x (choose x accordingly, so as per Cuda 10.1 (august,2019), the appropriate value for x is 3). So I basically installed CuDNN 7.6.3 for Cuda 10.1

**5)** Then, we have to add the bin, include, lib\x64 folders of Cuda to the System Path. (Note that include, lib\x64 will be added by default to the path after installing Cuda. So we just have to add the bin folder of Cuda to the path).

**6)** Next, we have to add the bin folder of CuDNN to the System Path.

**7)** Finally, type pip install TensorFlow in CMD, and restart your PC.

**Note that** if you have a different GPU, you can check the official websites of Cuda and CuDNN to check which versions of Cuda and CuDNN are compatible with respect to your GPU.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using anaconda then run this command in your anaconda prompt

`conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu`

This will also install the `cuda toolkit` and `cudnn` for you and you are good to go
 At website it mentions that this command is for linux so I am not sure whether it will work on window, but you can try

Comment: Just tried that & I get `PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:  - tesnorflow-gpu`

Comment: Are you using anaconda??? Go to Anaconda Prompt and type this command... because this command worked for me and made my life easier